# Items are removed from the list incorrectly

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I have some code that deletes the selected files in the list:

```
  Set set = selectedFileHashMap.keySet();
                Iterator itr = set.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Integer i = (Integer) itr.next();
                    ModelFile model = internalStorageFilesModelArrayList.get(i);
                    internalStorageFilesModelArrayList.remove(model);//remove file from ArrayList
                    File deleteFile = new File((String) selectedFileHashMap.get(i));//create file for selected file
                    boolean isDeleteFile = deleteFile.delete();//delete the file from memory
                    if (isDeleteFile) {
                        itr.remove();
                        selectedFileHashMap.remove(i);
                        /*selectedFileHashMap.remove(selectedFilePosition);*/
                    }
                }
```

The files deleted on the device correctly. In the RecyclerView, the first item is deleted, but then they are deleted  through one. I can't figure out how to solve the problem. I hope you can help...

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what exactly we want to achieve here? Also, please share your recycler view.

Comment: @NavjotSinghBedi I need to delete only selected files from the list. Now this code deletes the first selected position, and then after one. Because of this, if you delete all files, it gives an error like this: index = 2 size = 2

Comment: @NavjotSinghBedi I understood why this is happening.
This happens because the size of the list changes, but the position for deletion remains the same. Therefore, the element that took the place of the selected position is deleted.
I need to delete at once the positions from the list that are present in HashMap.